# How to package a single EXE with NuGet

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-spec

I have a large EXE that my project needs, but I don't want to commit large EXEs into Git.  So, seems to me a viable option is to pull it in through NuGet.  Easy enough, I created a .nuspec file with my one EXE in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Traefik</id>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <authors>Containous</authors>
        <owners>MikeC</owners>
        <projectUrl>https://github.com/containous/traefik</projectUrl>
        <license type="expression">MIT</license>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Traefik binaries</description>
        <copyright>Copyright ©2020 Containous</copyright>
    </metadata>

    <files>
        <file src="traefik.exe" target="lib" />
    </files>
</package>
```

I then run `nuget pack` and create a `.nupkg` file.  Everything is correct:

[image]

However, when I try to reference my NuGet package in my project, I get the following error right when clicking the "Install" button:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not install package 'Traefik 1.5.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Unsupported,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

This is a NuGet package that *has no* assemblies and nothing to reference.  It's simply content I want to pull in and copy somewhere using a post build action.  Is it possible to create a NuGet package that has no assemblies to reference and is purely content (in this case, a single EXE file)?  If so, what's the correct way to lay this out in the file structure?  I've tried putting the EXE in a few places, such as "bin", "tools", "content", etc.  Same error no matter what.  Thanks!

Comment: The `lib` folder is for referenced assemblies. If you don't want your executable to be added as a reference, `tools` is what you needed. You also need to set development dependency flag to true. https://github.com/obfuscar/obfuscar/blob/master/Obfuscar.nuspec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lib` folder is not suitable for this, because it is used for assemblies that your project **references** when installing the package. Apart from that, the folder structure must contain a [suitable target framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks) folder like `net472`. You cannot place assemblies directly unter `lib`.

```
<file src="traefik.exe" target="lib/net472"/>
```

If you want to treat your executable as a pure content file, you can use `contentFiles`.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <id>Traefik</id>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <authors>Containous</authors>
        <owners>MikeC</owners>
        <projectUrl>https://github.com/containous/traefik</projectUrl>
        <license type="expression">MIT</license>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>Traefik binaries</description>
        <copyright>Copyright ©2020 Containous</copyright>
        <contentFiles>
            <files include="any/any/traefik.exe" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true"/>
        </contentFiles>
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="traefik.exe" target="contentFiles/any/any/traefik.exe"/>
        <file src="traefik.exe" target="content/traefik.exe"/>
    </files>
</package>
```

This way, the `traefik.exe` will be copied directly to your output folder. Inside of your package, the folder structure will be like this. This folder structure is predefined for content files.

```
content
    - traefik.exe
contentFiles
    - any
        - any
            - traefik.exe
```

You can even target a distinct or multiple frameworks with this approach. Say you have a special executable for .NET Framework 4.7.2, then adapt the second `any` to your [target framework moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks), here `net472`. The executable will then only be copied to your output folder if the framework matches your project framework.

```
<files include="any/net472/traefik.exe" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true"/>
<file src="traefik.exe" target="contentFiles/any/net472/traefik.exe"/>
```

Of course, you can define multiple executables for different frameworks like this. A few remarks about the NuSpec file. The executable is also copied to the `content` folder of your package for backwards compatibility, because `contentFiles` is supported only since *NuGet 4.0* using `PackageReference`.